# How to get list number in <ol> to match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery UI sortable. The list items contain hidden input fields. I want the value of the name attribute to change depending on the list items location in the ordered list.

Here's what I have so far,

```
<ol id='externs'>
    <li>
        fred
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="203">
    </li>
    <li>
        joe
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="993">
    </li>
</ol>
<ol id='interns'>
    <li>
        suzy
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="2">
    </li>
    <li>
        marty
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="13">
    </li>
    <li>
        foofoo
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="201">
    </li>

</ol>
```

And the jQuery I have so far...

```
$('#externs li input').attr('name','e_'+n);
$('#interns li input').attr('name','i_'+n);
```

Where n=the order in the list. Perhaps putting this in some kind of loop would work?

The resulting HTML should be...

```
<ol id='externs'>
    <li>
        fred
        <input type="hidden" name="e_1" value="203">
    </li>
    <li>
        joe
        <input type="hidden" name="e_2" value="993">
    </li>
</ol>
<ol id='interns'>
    <li>
        suzy
        <input type="hidden" name="i_1" value="2">
    </li>
    <li>
        marty
        <input type="hidden" name="i_2" value="13">
    </li>
    <li>
        foofoo
        <input type="hidden" name="i_3" value="201">
    </li>

</ol>
```

EDIT:

Should have also posted my jQuery UI sortable code. I need the code to run whenever I drag and drop stuff. Should I use an eventListener? Or can I hook up my code to this:

```
    $( "#externs, #interns" ).sortable({
        dropOnEmpty: true
    }).disableSelection();
```

EDIT 2:

I ended up just running the code on click:

```
    $('#screen-students').click(function(){

        $('#externs li input').attr('name', function(index) {
            return 'e_' + (index + 1);
        });

        $('#interns li input').attr('name', function(index) {
            return 'i_' + (index + 1);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an callback function to `.attr`:

```
$('#externs li input').attr('name', function(index) {
  return 'e_' + (index + 1);
});

$('#interns li input').attr('name', function(index) {
  return 'i_' + (index + 1);
});
```

Comment: This is very nice! How would I hook this into the sortable plugin?

Comment: nevermind, i just hooked it up to my submit button's click event

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#externs li input').each(function(index)  { 
      $(this).attr('name','e_'+index);
  });
  $('#interns li input').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('name','i_' + index);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: oh, this would give you indexes starting at 0. You may need to do index +1 to achieve the numbering you need.

Comment: Yes! I just realized this. Is using `each` faster than xdazz's solution?

Comment: not so sure, maybe @xdazz 's version might be a bit faster but you'd have to measure ( I recall some post somewhere saying each() is not the fastest of all calls)

Answer (score 0):

```
var eCount = $("#externs").children("li").length;
var iCount = $("#interns").children("li").length;

for (var i =1 ; i < eCount;i++)
{
$("#externs").find("input").eq(i-1).attr('name','e_'+i);
}

for (var j =1 ; j < eCount;j++)
{
$("#interns").find("input").eq(j-1).attr('name','i_'+j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var elength = $("#externs").find("li").length;
   var ilength = $("#interns").find("li").length;

    for (var i =1 ; i < elength;i++)
    {
      $("#externs").find("input").eq(i-1).attr('name','e_'+i);
    }

    for (var j =1 ; j < ilength;j++)
    {
      $("#interns").find("input").eq(j-1).attr('name','i_'+j);
    }
});
```

Here is working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vp5U4/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#externs, #interns').each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).find('input').attr('id', function (i) {
        return id[0] + '_' + i;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VqLM4/)